# Scrapy, limit on start_url

Tags: python, scrapy

I am wondering whether there is a limit on the number of `start_urls` I can assign to my spider? 
As far as I've searched, there seems to be no documentation on the limit of the list.

Currently I have set my spider so that the list of `start_urls` is read in from a csv file. The number of urls is around 1,000,000.

Answer (score 10):

There isn't a limit per se but you probably want to limit it yourself, otherwise you might end up with memory problems.
What can happen is all those 1M urls will be scheduled to scrapy scheduler and since python objects are quite a bit heavier than plain strings you'll end up running out of memory.

To avoid this you can batch your start urls with `spider_idle` signal:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "spider"
    urls = []
    batch_size = 10000

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = cls(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.idle_consume, signals.spider_idle)
        return spider 

    def __init__(self, crawler):
        self.crawler = crawler
        self.urls = [] # read from file

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            url = self.urls.pop(0)
            yield Request(url)


    def parse(self, response):
        pass
        # parse

    def idle_consume(self):
        """
        Everytime spider is about to close check our urls 
        buffer if we have something left to crawl
        """
        reqs = self.start_requests()
        if not reqs:
            return
        logging.info('Consuming batch')
        for req in reqs:
            self.crawler.engine.schedule(req, self)
        raise DontCloseSpider
```

Comment: Thank you Granitosaurus, the help was much appreciated :)

Comment: Nice workaround, but it doesn't work with async generators.