# Scrapy spider not yielding all start_requests urls in broad crawl

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to create a scraper that crawls the homepages and some amount of deeper pages from >300.000 start_urls. The code runs without significant errors, but stops after only 31.000 urls.
The scrapy logs show that 'finished_reason' = 'finished'.

**I do not understand the reason for Scrapy to be finished, while not all urls from start_requests are scraped. **

The code below shows the spider I run.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from datetime import datetime
from twisted.internet.error import DNSLookupError, TCPTimedOutError, ConnectionLost
from scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror import HttpError
import pandas as pd

# To run: scrapy crawl gptspider -s -o output.json --logfile logfile.txt


class TextSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "gptspider"

    # Settings to optimize for our broad crawl, as recommended by https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html
    custom_settings = {
        "SCHEDULER_PRIORITY_QUEUE": "scrapy.pqueues.DownloaderAwarePriorityQueue",
        "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS": 100,
        "REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE": 20,
        "USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36",
    }

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super(TextSpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
        self.progress_counter = 0
        self.MAX_DEPTH = 0
        self.companies_with_valid_url = []
        self.allowed_domains = []
        urlfilepath = "PATH_TO_CSV_WITH_OVER_100k_ULRS"
        companyurls = pd.read_csv(urlfilepath)
        for i, row in companyurls.iterrows():
            some_property = row["Some_propoerty"]
            url = row["website"]
            if url is not None and type(url) == str:
                base_url = TextSpider.convert_url_to_base(url)
                self.companies_with_valid_url.append(
                    {"some_property": some_property, "base_url": base_url}
                )
                self.allowed_domains.append(urlparse(base_url).netloc)

    # Put URLS into the right format
    @staticmethod
    def convert_url_to_base(url):
        if url is not None and type(url) == str:
            if not (
                url.startswith("//")
                or url.startswith("http://")
                or url.startswith("https://")
            ):
                url = "//" + url
            url = urlparse(url).netloc
            if ("http" in url) & (url[-1:] == "/"):
                return url
            elif ("http" in url) & (url[-1:] != "/"):
                return url + "/"
            elif ("http" not in url) & (url[-1:] == "/"):
                return "http://" + url
            else:
                return "http://" + url + "/"
        return url

    def start_requests(self):
        print(
            f"Starting requests for {len(self.companies_with_valid_url)} URLS"
        )  # Output Starting requests for 320833 companies
        for companyurl in self.companies_with_valid_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=companyurl["base_url"],
                callback=self.parse,
                errback=self.handle_error,
                dont_filter=True,
                meta={"some_property": companyurl["some_property"]},
            )
        print("THIS NEVER PRINTS")

    # Parse the response, extract the visible text and scrape the subpages
    def parse(self, response):
        if self.progress_counter % 100 == 0:
            print(self.progress_counter)
            print(datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
        self.progress_counter += 1

        # THIS IS NOT YET USED
        if response.meta["depth"] < self.MAX_DEPTH:
            # Get a list of all the sub-pages to scrape
            sub_pages = response.xpath("//a/@href").getall()
            # Yield requests to scrape the sub-pages
            for sub_page in sub_pages:
                yield response.follow(
                    sub_page,
                    callback=self.parse,
                    errback=self.handle_error,
                    dont_filter=True,
                    meta={"some_property": response.request.meta["some_property"]},
                )

        # Yield the scraped text and the URL it came from
        return self.response_to_data(response)

    def handle_error(self, failure):

        if failure.check(HttpError):
            error_status = failure.value.response.status

        elif failure.check(DNSLookupError):
            error_status = "DNSLookupError"

        elif failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError):
            error_status = "TCPTimedOutError"
        elif failure.check(ConnectionLost):
            error_status = "ConnectionLost"
        else:
            error_status = "Other error"

        # add depth variable if not included (can happen under some error circumstances)
        if "depth" not in failure.request.meta:
            failure.request.meta["depth"] = 0

        return {
            "some_property": failure.request.meta["some_property"],
            "url": failure.request.url,
            "depth": failure.request.meta["depth"],
            "response_code": error_status,
            "scraped_at": datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
            "text": failure.getErrorMessage(),
            "failure": 1,
        }

    def response_to_data(self, response):
        return {
            "some_property": response.request.meta["some_property"],
            "url": response.url,
            "depth": response.request.meta["depth"],
            "response_code": response.status,
            "scraped_at": datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
            "text": self.extract_visible_text(response),
            "failure": 0,
        }

    # Extract the visible text from a scrapy HttpResponse
    def extract_visible_text(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

        if response.status == 200 or response.status == 304:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
            # Removes all script and style tags
            for script in soup(["style", "script"]):
                script.decompose()

            # If no "body" tag in the html text, the firms will be classified as unlabeled
            if soup.find("body") == None:
                return "NODATA_NO_BODY_TAG"
            else:
                html = soup.get_text()
                html = " ".join(html.split())
                visible_text = re.sub(r"(?<![A-Z])(?<!^)([A-Z])", r" \1", html)
                # visible_text = html
                # Handle surrogates
                visible_text = visible_text.encode("utf-8", "surrogateescape").decode(
                    "utf-8", "replace"
                )
                return visible_text
        else:
            return {"text": "NODATA_BAD_RESPONSE_CODE"}
```

I tried adapting the settings (as seen in the Spider code) to conform with Scrapy's recommendation for broad crawls, but without succes.

I also tried to inspect the last logs to see what happens before the program finishes. I did notice that there was a 'User timeout caused connection failure' error before the finish (see log exerpt below), but those happen accross the logs and should not cause the program to finish as far as I understand.

```
...

Getting http://www.okaidi.be/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..', 'failure': 1}
2023-01-04 12:09:48 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-01-04 12:09:48 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (3040 items) in: output11.json
2023-01-04 12:09:48 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
...
```

Edit:

The summary (end) of the logfile

```
2023-01-04 17:52:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-01-04 17:52:34 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (34754 items) in: output33.json
2023-01-04 17:52:34 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 9531,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/idna.core.InvalidCodepoint': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest': 355,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError': 49,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 6360,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError': 1139,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 20,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseFailed': 24,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 1583,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 33338047,
 'downloader/request_count': 138042,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 138042,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 995846155,
 'downloader/response_count': 128866,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 59652,
 'downloader/response_status_count/202': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 48480,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 7107,
 'downloader/response_status_count/303': 210,
 'downloader/response_status_count/307': 176,
 'downloader/response_status_count/308': 464,
 'downloader/response_status_count/400': 29,
 'downloader/response_status_count/401': 11,
 'downloader/response_status_count/402': 5,
 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 1260,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 8688,
 'downloader/response_status_count/405': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/406': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/409': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/410': 56,
 'downloader/response_status_count/418': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/429': 156,
 'downloader/response_status_count/456': 6,
 'downloader/response_status_count/500': 1709,
 'downloader/response_status_count/502': 47,
 'downloader/response_status_count/503': 654,
 'downloader/response_status_count/504': 27,
 'downloader/response_status_count/510': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/520': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/521': 7,
 'downloader/response_status_count/522': 87,
 'downloader/response_status_count/523': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/524': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/526': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/999': 14,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2787.423471,
 'feedexport/success_count/FileFeedStorage': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 4, 16, 52, 34, 847868),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 3578050995,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 53590,
 'item_scraped_count': 34754,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 684335,
 'log_count/ERROR': 5348,
 'log_count/INFO': 57,
 'log_count/WARNING': 426,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 70239,
 'retry/count': 7823,
 'retry/max_reached': 3814,
 'retry/reason_count/429 Unknown Status': 118,
 'retry/reason_count/500 Internal Server Error': 994,
 'retry/reason_count/502 Bad Gateway': 32,
 'retry/reason_count/503 Service Unavailable': 436,
 'retry/reason_count/504 Gateway Time-out': 19,
 'retry/reason_count/522 Unknown Status': 58,
 'retry/reason_count/524 Unknown Status': 2,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError': 31,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 4240,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError': 804,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 14,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseFailed': 16,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 1059,
 "robotstxt/exception_count/<class 'idna.core.InvalidCodepoint'>": 1,
 "robotstxt/exception_count/<class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError'>": 9,
 "robotstxt/exception_count/<class 'twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError'>": 1094,
 "robotstxt/exception_count/<class 'twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError'>": 163,
 "robotstxt/exception_count/<class 'twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError'>": 3,
 "robotstxt/exception_count/<class 'twisted.web._newclient.ResponseFailed'>": 2,
 "robotstxt/exception_count/<class 'twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived'>": 261,
 'robotstxt/forbidden': 355,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 38926,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 37332,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 28193,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/400': 16,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/401': 6,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/402': 3,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/403': 618,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/404': 8084,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/405': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/406': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/409': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/410': 28,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/418': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/429': 19,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/500': 242,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/502': 6,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/503': 86,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/504': 2,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/510': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/520': 2,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/521': 3,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/522': 13,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/523': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/526': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/999': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 72075,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 72075,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 72075,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 72075,
 'spider_exceptions/ValueError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 4, 16, 6, 7, 424397)}
2023-01-04 17:52:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: if you have the logs can you share the stats you get at the end please? are the requests being blocked ? are they being filtered because they are duplicates ? are they reaching the url length limit maybe ?

Comment: I have added the log stats. I checked, and there should be over 200k unique URLs, while the scraping stops after 31k.

Comment: it's really hard to debug this considering i don't have full info but can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43532976/scrapy-limit-on-start-url maybe it will help you

Comment: Run your spider again and copy the full logs to a pastebin and then post the link to the pastebin in your question.  Based on the limited information it sounds like you are being throttled at one end of the network.  probably your end

Comment: @zaki98, following the advice on the link you suggested has solved the issue. Thank you!
However, I do not fully understand why. Checking the resource monitor, there was no apparent memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice on [Scrapy, limit on start_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43532976/scrapy-limit-on-start-url) from @granitosaurus and adapted the code as suggested to scrape in batches.
This seems to have worked. The program now scrapes all the url's.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).